# Submenus node cli

Tags: javascript, nodejs

estoy realizando un pequeño CLI de node para ver cómo funcionan realmente. Mi duda es a la hora de hacer submenús, es decir yo tengo este menu:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

una vez seleccionado una opción de esas, quiero preguntar al usuario si realmente quiere realizar esa acción, el mítico y/n, y en caso de no desearlo volver a comenzar en el menú principal.

El CLI lo tengo desarrollado de la siguiente manera:

```
(async () => {
msn('FMG-CLI');
selectOption(await cliMenu());
})();
```

y el menú principal:

```
const options = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Create directory' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Create file' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Delete file' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Rename file' }
];

//menu
const cliMenu = () => {
    const menu = [
        {
            type: "list",
            name: "menu",
            message: "Select an option:",
            choices: [options[0].name, options[1].name, options[2].name, options[3].name]
        }
    ];

    return inquirer.prompt(menu).then(answer => { optionJSON = JSON.stringify(answer, null, " ") });
```

}

lo que quiero saber principalmente es como jugar con la interacción de menus y la gestión de respuestas.

Agradezco vuestra ayuda.

Un saludo